# Why does a method override which does nothing more than call the super implementation crashes my app

Tags: android, android-support-library

For the purpose of understanding the Android life cycle in a simple `android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity#AppCompatActivity` I was overriding many "on" methods to log their execution.

I added the following:

```
// This override will crash app!
override fun onCreateView(name: String?, context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?): View {
    //log {"onCreateView(3)"}
    return super.onCreateView(name, context, attrs)
}
```

The result is the app now crashes with:

```
06-18 06:56:54.627 1004-1004/com.hanafey.prefone E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.hanafey.prefone, PID: 1004
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.hanafey.prefone/com.hanafey.prefone.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class LinearLayout
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class LinearLayout
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:3605)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3677)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.getDecorView(PhoneWindow.java:1943)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:374)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:323)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
        at com.hanafey.prefone.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:165)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: super.onCreateView(name, context, attrs) must not be null
        at com.hanafey.prefone.MainActivity.onCreateView(MainActivity.kt:59)
        at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:5325)
        at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi14.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityApi14.java:41)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:68)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:733)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:3605) 
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3677) 
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.getDecorView(PhoneWindow.java:1943) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:374) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:323) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
        at com.hanafey.prefone.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:165) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

(even the log statement was removed to make it a pure non-override override)

**Reflexively I would say this kind of override is just a no-op -- useless but harmless.**

I guess it must be caused by some reflection in the baggage of the hack to support old platforms, but it would be nice to understand what the real issue is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the super can return null but your return type is not nullable.  If you changed it to the following it would work:

```
override fun onCreateView(name: String?, context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?): View? {
    //log {"onCreateView(3)"}
    return super.onCreateView(name, context, attrs)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The IDE should not indicate that the method without the nullable return time is a valid override of the java method, and it can even suggest the fix. It is also clear now that the exception does clearly indicate the reason for the error at runtime.